# Invincible and Prudhoe (Bay) class Starships

Tags: star-trek

What is the comparison between Invincible and Prudhoe class Starships? Memory Gamma Wiki has an article on the Invincible but not the Prudhoe class. The only thing I have found is a graphic on the Prudhoe (Bay) class. It mentions that it is a prototype and that's all. Is there anywhere that I can find the info I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you post the graphic? I'm not seeing anything about that class of ship on any of the usual websites.

Comment: http://memory-gamma.wikia.com/wiki/Invincible_class

Comment: Yuk. I'm finding all kinds of [fan-made stuff](http://www.geocities.ws/dos_geek/Prudhoe.html) about the [USS Prudhoe Bay](http://startrek.fantasy-web.net/an/lod.php?id=1505), largely based on other [fan-made stuff](http://www.inpayne.com/models/kitbash/trekpage_lion.html) that they've cannibalised for spares

Comment: I got smarter and did a search of its registry number. The ship name that came up was USS COEUR DE LION NCC-3135, not the Prudhom. So far I have only found out that it was the largest and most heavily armed of battleship class. I am looking a bit deeper.

Comment: Forgot to mention this before, unfortunately no URL accompanied the graphic I got off the Internet.

Comment: That [Coeur De Lion class ship](http://www.inpayne.com/models/kitbash/trekpage_lion.html) is a fan-created kit.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was about as comprehensive as you're going to see. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 1):

Delving deep into the weird and wacky world of Star Trek RPG fan-made properties, it appears that the FASA '[Federation Ship Recognition Manual - 2385 Edition](http://engineering.thetafleet.net/Journals/TNG/FASA%20-%20Federation%20Ship%20Recognition%20Manual%202385.pdf)' contains a reference to a Bay-Class Destroyer. One of the ships in that class was the NCC-23103 **USS Prudhoe Bay** (p168).

Assuming this is what you're referring to, you may want to note that the authors indicated that this vessel was intended to operate in fleets of 8+

> *Any Bay by itself is a weak warship and is barely capable of
>   self-defense*

In comparison the [Invincible-class](http://memory-gamma.wikia.com/wiki/Invincible_class) starship mentioned on Memory Gamma is a veritable beast, well equipped to take on entire fleets of enemy vessels.

> *The Invincible-class is the single largest multi-mission
>   combat-equipped starship ever constructed by Starfleet. ... Invincible-class ships combine the roles of battleship and fighter carrier, having a massive offensive capability in terms of on-board weapons and huge complement of space dominance fighters.*